# Why does this function return different values than it prints?

Tags: python

Beginner question - I'm trying to solve [CodeAbbey's Problem #174](https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/calculation-of-pi), "Calculation of Pi", and so far I have written a function that accurately calculates the sidelengths of a regular Polygon with 6*N corners, thus approximating a circle.

In the code below, the function x(R,d) *prints* the correct values for "h" and "side" (compare the values given in the example on CodeAbbey), but when I ran my code through pythontutor, I saw that it *returns* slightly different values, for example 866025403784438700 instead of 866025403784438646 for the first value of h.

Can someone help me understand why this is?

As you can probably tell, I'm an amateur. I took the isqrt function from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577821-integer-square-root-function/), as the math.sqrt(x) method seems to give very imprecise results for large values of x

```py
def isqrt(x):
    # Returns the integer square root. This seems to be unproblematic
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError('square root not defined for negative numbers')
    n = int(x)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    a, b = divmod(n.bit_length(), 2)
    x = 2**(a+b)
    while True:
        y = (x + n//x)//2
        if y >= x:
            return x
        x = y


def x(R,d):
        # given Radius and sidelength of initial polygon,
        # this should return sidelength of new polygon.
    h = isqrt(R**2 - d**2)
    side = isqrt(d**2 + (R-h)**2)
    print (h, side)             # the values in this line are slightly
    return (h, side)            # different than the ones here. Why?


def approximate_pi(K,N):
    R = int(10**K)
    d = R // 2
    for i in range(N):
        d = (x(R,d)[1] // 2)
    return int(6 * 2**(N) * d)


print (approximate_pi(18,4))
```

Comment: That sounds more like an artifact of pythontutor than anything actually wrong with your code. pythontutor is not a fully compliant Python implementation.

Comment: It sounds like pythontutor is using floating point for large integers, rather than multiprecision integers. So large numbers lose accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

That's an artifact of Python Tutor. It's not something actually happening in your code.

From a very brief look at the [Python Tutor source code](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/tree/master/v5-unity), it looks like the Python execution backend is a slightly hacked-up, *mostly* standard CPython instance with debug instrumentation through [`bdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bdb.html), but the visualization is in Javascript. The printed output comes from the Python standard output, but the visualization goes through Javascript, and the Python integers get converted to Javascript Number values, losing precision because Number is 64-bit floating point.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with rounding to the nearest integer.
In your function `divmod(n.bit_length(), 2)`, try to change 2 to 2.0, it will give similar value to what you saw on their plateform.